# Bayes Factor Bound computation

Tags: r, bayesian, p-value

I recently read this interesting work

Daniel J. Benjamin & James O. Berger (2019) Three Recommendations for Improving the Use of p-Values, The American Statistician, 73:sup1, 186-191, DOI: 10.1080/00031305.2018.1543135

and created a code to compute the Bayes Factor Bound (BFB) as suggested (see picture and code below; where p is the p-value and *e* should be the Euler number)

[image]

However, I am quite puzzled by the output I get for extremely non-significant results (e.g., p = 0.75 and over) (see plot).
[image]

How is it possible that a p-value of 0.991 is equal to a BFB of 41, where BFB is defined as "the strongest case for the alternative hypothesis relative to the null hypothesis"(Benjamin and Berger, 2019)? Is my code wrong or am I missing something?

Many thanks!

```
df = data_frame()
for(p in  seq(0.001:1, by = 0.01)){
  
  BFB <- round(1/-(2.71*p*log(p)),2)

  output = c(BFB,p)
  df = rbind(df, output)
}
colnames(df)<-c("BFB", "p-value")

ggplot(df, aes(`p-value`,BFB))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth()+
  theme_bw()+
  xlim(min(df$`p-value`), max(df$`p-value`))
```

Comment: You may want to avoid `for` loop using this: `p <- seq(0.001:1, by = 0.01);
BFB <- round(1/-(exp(1)*p*log(p)),2);
df <- data.frame(BFB = BFB, "p-value" = p, check.names = FALSE)`  The loop is not needed since these operations are vectorized in R.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is implemented correctly; however, BFB values for large `p` are not meaningful.

Slide 4 from the [webinar](https://www.niss.org/sites/default/files/berger_3_recommendations.pdf) indicates that the formula is for `p < exp(-1)`. The BFB value is meant to accompany relatively small p-values. When `p > exp(-1)` it is neither suggestive nor significant. I don't see the value of a bound on the BF in that case.